# Concatenating int to char[]

Tags: c

I'm new to C (obviously) and I am getting the following error:

`warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strncat’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]`

Here is the code:

```
int main(void)
{
  FILE *fp;
  int c;
  unsigned char file[1024] = "/path/to/file";
  unsigned char text[1024] = "SomeText";

  fp = fopen(file, "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
  {
    perror("Error opening file");
    return(-1);
  }

  while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n')
  {
    strncat(text,c,1);
  }
}
```

Obviously this makes sense to me but unfortunately not the compiler. How would I write this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strncat` cannot append a character to a string, because it appends strings to strings. You can make a one-character string from your `c` character, but using `strcat` is an overkill: you would be better off making a pointer, and appending by adding characters to it:

```
char *p = &text[strlen(text)]; // Start appending at the last position of text
while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n') {
    *p++ = c;
    if (p == &text[1023]) break;
}
*p = '\0';
```

Pointer check in the loop has been added to deal with buffer overruns.

Answer (score 2):

There is no implicit conversion between an integer and a string representing the value stored in the integer. You must manually convert it.

Function `itoa` can do it for you:

```
int value = 1234;
char tempBuffer[MAX_DIGITS];
itoa(value, tempBuffer, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

`strcat()` concatenates two strings, and a C string is an array with a terminating `'\0'` character. So this is a mismatch.

However, `strncat()` concatenates two strings and let's you set the maximum number of characters to copy. So you could pass the address of the `c` and it will be treated like an array with only one element. So you could try something like this:

```
strncat(text, (char*)&c, 1);
```

Otherwise, you need a character buffer to hold this stuff.

Comment: It turns into a warning and I get this: `note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
 extern char *strncat (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src,`

Comment: I added a fix for that.

Comment: Got it now.  Is this considered bad practice?  How does this compare to the above methods?

Comment: It's a little non-standard, but there's nothing about it I would consider bad practice. When you pass a char array, you pass the address of the first element. So, here, I'm just passing the address of a single character and treating it as an array with one item. The only thing to be mindful of is that there is no terminating `'\0'` at the end of the array. That's why the last argument `1` is very important to `strncat()`.

Comment: It's a little more direct than the other suggestions, and uses less memory for it (although that may not be important).

Comment: This depends on endianness, but funny approach otherwise :)

Answer (score 0):

strncat is for concatenating (C-style) strings. `text` is a char[], so that works, but `c` is an int, which is definitely not a string, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

try this
 `strncat(text, &c,1)`